# How to Show Alert Dialog From net standard

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, xamarin

I have an android project with reference to the net standard library that I have created.

I want to show the alert dialog. But It needs context from activity, while I can not call activity from the net standard library.

The idea I want to parse Activity as object to my library. Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solusion.
The idea come from plugin called CurrentActivityPlugin that created by James Montemagno ([CurrentActivityPlugin](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/CurrentActivityPlugin)).

I didn't use this plugin because I already have class that inherit Application.
So i use ActivityLifecycleCallbacks, and implement it on the class that inherit Application. The idea come from this article [Sample usage of the "android.app.Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks" class.](https://gist.github.com/petterh/ad5e52859bb906b9ac4da784ea568d7a)

And this article
[How to use ActivityLifecycleCallbacks in Application Class](http://baroqueworksdev.blogspot.co.id/2012/12/how-to-use-activitylifecyclecallbacks.html)

Hope this can help somebody that have same problem like me.